# Redirected domains only picking up part of the CSS file

Tags: css, cross-domain

I have a site at my domain `example.com` that I got through a shared hosting company.

I have just got additional domains for `example.co.uk` and `example.ie` but have not got hosting with them just the domains.

These domains are redirecting to `example.com` and this works fine.

However on mobile the desktop version of the Site is being displayed when going to `example.co.uk` and `example.ie`.

I only have one stylesheet which has `@media` queries for desktop and mobile on `example.com` like so:

```
/* --------------MOBILE-------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){

}

/* --------------DESKTOP-------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){

}
```

My site at example.com follows these rules and displays as expected but even though the other domains are just redirecting here it only seems to read the desktop style.

I have set the viewport like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Just a further point... It will display the mobile CSS on desktop when you make the window small enough it just won't load properly on an actual mobile device

Comment: Nothing of the rudimentary code snippets you provided would explain this. You need to either set up a proper [mcve] (probably not that easy in this case), or at least show us this thing “live” …

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your comment, yeah it's a bit of a strange one to get an example of. The domains in question are lifting365.com .ie and .co.uk

Comment: Ah, that’s what I suspected - your “redirects” from the other two domains aren’t actual redirects (then lifting365.com would show in the address bar in all three cases), but just framesets that embed the content from lifting365.com … that is just a bad setup. Get proper redirects put in place instead, then this problem will dissolve itself into thin air automatically.

Comment: Ah ok thanks makes sense. I'm with a shared hosting company and they just had an automatic redirect thing going on so I didn't change any DNS records or anything. Is there a way to do this that would allow me to keep the URL in the address bar as the domain that was entered (.ie or .co.uk) but still redirect properly

Comment: Not with a redirect, no. You could set these domains as alias domains for your main domain, if the hosting allows for this. But that’s likely to cause problems regarding “duplicate content” with search engines (unless you specify canonical to point to the main domain for all three, but if you did that, the search engines would only link to that main domain, so having three different ones might be rather pointless to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe Cool thanks for your help